# convert html page into editable pdf in iOS

Tags: html, ios, pdf-generation

I want to convert any HTML page into an editable PDF with its all contents like images. I don't want to create pdf of screenshots rather an editable pdf. Any links or ideas are welcome.

Comment: What do you mean by editable?

Comment: editable means i can use pdf like that page.. I can select text and i can go to specific page if the content is linked..